# Code is working only if the breakpoint is placed in a method c#

Tags: c#, .net, mouseevent

I have a left mouse down event. My application is working as expected only if I place a breakpoint in this method. If I remove the breakpoint and run the code the functionality is not working.

Is there any specific reason why this is happening?? PFB event code

```
internal void LeftMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        recorderData.CloseRecordedActionWindows();

        if (CommonRecorderHelper.IsCursorInsideRecorder())
            return;

                      recorderData.m_lastPremitiveAction = PrimitiveMouseEvent.LeftButtonDown.ToString();
        recorderData.m_lastMouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        recorderData.m_IsAssertionStarted = false;
        recorderData.m_readyForHookDisconnect = false;
        recorderData.m_previousKeyboardSUITControl = null;

        recorderData.m_RecordedValue.ResetValues(!recorderData.m_RecordedValue.IsModifierKeyPressed());

        if (recorderData.m_RecordedValue.IsModifierKeyPressed())
            recorderData.m_IsModifierKeyPressedForMouseAction = true;

        UpdateRecorderFormWithActions(recorderData.m_lastMouseDownLocation, PrimitiveMouseEvent.LeftButtonDown);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        recorderData.m_RecordingStopped = true;
        recorderData.m_mouseDownOnValidationBtn = false;
        SUITLogger.ReportMessage(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
                recorderData.m_EarlierX = e.X;
        recorderData.m_EarlierY = e.Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post complete code?

Comment: At which point of the code is the breakpoint set when it works? Can you show the definition for the type of recorderData?

Comment: This might happen if you are reading something that's gonna change in another thread or for example needs more time to load. When you place breakpoint you give the code time to load or other thread to finish. For us to be able to know what's the case you should give more details about what you want to do and how you want to do it.

Comment: @DarrenGansberg.. It works only when I place break point at :::if (CommonRecorderHelper.IsCursorInsideRecorder()) -->This if condition

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because it is taking more time for the other thread to finish.When I'm making the thread to sleep it is working as expected without any break point.

If we are placing the breakpoint, we are giving time to the code before the other thread finish..

Answer (score 1):

By placing a break point on `if (CommonRecorderHelper.IsCursorInsideRecorder())`, the debugger will stop when it hits that line and the cursor will be moved to the code window - thus leave your recorder window.

So I think that your question was not well-worded. Actually, your code works always. Only that `IsCursorInsideRecorder` function normally returns `true` while you expect it to return `false`.